Upgrading OpenLayers JavaScript version, getting Uncaught TypeError: ol.inherits is not a function
I am trying to upgrade the ol version from 2.0 to 10.1. After I replaced the old ol.js file with the latest version, I am start getting error of Uncaught TypeError: ol.inherits is not a function
Here is the code
    ol.control.LayerSwitcher = function(opt_options) 
    {
        var options = opt_options || {};
        var self = this;
        this.dcount = 0;
        this.show_progress = options.show_progress;
        this.oninfo = (typeof (options.oninfo) == "function" ? options.oninfo: null);
        this.onextent = (typeof (options.onextent) == "function" ? options.onextent: null);
        this.hasextent = options.extent || options.onextent;
        this.hastrash = options.trash;
        this.reordering = (options.reordering!==false);

        var element;

        if (options.target) 
        {   element = $("<div>").addClass(options.switcherClass || "ol-layerswitcher");
        }
        else
        {   element = $("<div>").addClass((options.switcherClass || 'ol-layerswitcher') +' ol-unselectable ol-control ol-collapsed');

            element.addClass("ol-forceopen"); 
            self.overflow();
        
            this.button = $("<button>")
                        .on("touchstart", function(e)
                        {   element.toggleClass("ol-collapsed"); 
                            e.preventDefault(); 
                            self.overflow();
                        })
                        .click (function()
                        {   element.toggleClass("ol-forceopen").addClass("ol-collapsed"); 
                            self.overflow();
                        })
                        .appendTo(element);
            if (options.mouseover)
            {   
                $(element).mouseleave (function(){ element.addClass("ol-collapsed"); })
                    .mouseover(function(){ element.removeClass("ol-collapsed"); });
            }
            this.topv = $("<div>").addClass("ol-switchertopdiv")
                .click(function(){ self.overflow("+50%"); })
                .appendTo(element);
            this.botv = $("<div>").addClass("ol-switcherbottomdiv")
                .click(function(){ self.overflow("-50%"); })
                .appendTo(element);
        }
        this.panel_ = $("<ul>").addClass("panel")
                    .appendTo(element);
        this.panel_.on ('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll onmousewheel', function(e)
            {   if (self.overflow(Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail)))))
                {   e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        this.header_ = $("<li>").addClass("ol-header").appendTo(this.panel_);

        ol.control.Control.call(this, 
        {   element: element.get(0),
            target: options.target
        });

        // Enable jQuery dataTransfert
        // $.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
        this.target = options.target;

    };
    ol.inherits(ol.control.LayerSwitcher, ol.control.Control);

With the help of chatgtp, Replace the ol.inherits function with native class inheritance.
    class LayerSwitcher extends ol.control.Control {
        constructor(opt_options) {
            super({
                element: element.get(0),
                target: opt_options.target,
            });
            var options = opt_options || {};
            var self = this;
            this.dcount = 0;
            this.show_progress = options.show_progress;
            this.oninfo = (typeof (options.oninfo) == "function" ? options.oninfo: null);
            this.onextent = (typeof (options.onextent) == "function" ? options.onextent: null);
            this.hasextent = options.extent || options.onextent;
            this.hastrash = options.trash;
            this.reordering = (options.reordering!==false);

            var element;

            if (options.target) 
            {   element = $("<div>").addClass(options.switcherClass || "ol-layerswitcher");
            }
            else
            {   element = $("<div>").addClass((options.switcherClass || 'ol-layerswitcher') +' ol-unselectable ol-control ol-collapsed');

                element.addClass("ol-forceopen"); 
                self.overflow();
            
                this.button = $("<button>")
                            .on("touchstart", function(e)
                            {   element.toggleClass("ol-collapsed"); 
                                e.preventDefault(); 
                                self.overflow();
                            })
                            .click (function()
                            {   element.toggleClass("ol-forceopen").addClass("ol-collapsed"); 
                                self.overflow();
                            })
                            .appendTo(element);
                if (options.mouseover)
                {   
                    $(element).mouseleave (function(){ element.addClass("ol-collapsed"); })
                        .mouseover(function(){ element.removeClass("ol-collapsed"); });
                }
                this.topv = $("<div>").addClass("ol-switchertopdiv")
                    .click(function(){ self.overflow("+50%"); })
                    .appendTo(element);
                this.botv = $("<div>").addClass("ol-switcherbottomdiv")
                    .click(function(){ self.overflow("-50%"); })
                    .appendTo(element);
            }
            this.panel_ = $("<ul>").addClass("panel")
                        .appendTo(element);
            this.panel_.on ('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll onmousewheel', function(e)
                {   if (self.overflow(Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail)))))
                    {   e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            this.header_ = $("<li>").addClass("ol-header").appendTo(this.panel_);

            ol.control.Control.call(this, 
            {   element: element.get(0),
                target: options.target
            });

            // Enable jQuery dataTransfert
            // $.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
            this.target = options.target;
        }

        // other methods...
    }
    ol.inherits(new LayerSwitcher(), ol.control.Control);

Now further getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get').
I can't find any example that can relate to my piece of code. Can anyone suggest me how to get it fixed.

Just insert the below code before layer switcher definition:
<script>
  ol.inherits = function(child,parent) {
    child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
  };
</script>

But I doubt such an old code would work with the latest OL.
